# Cross-tabulate timestamp for two tables in ArcGIS

Tags: python, sql, arcgis

I am trying to work out a problem in ArcGIS 10.2 and I need to use either Python or even an SQL statement to complete this task.  I have three datasets:

-A polygon grid with a unique ID
-A point feature class (A) representing GPS data that was collected every 3 seconds with a time stamp and an ID number of GPS unit
-A point feature class (B) representing a specific event that occurred with a timestamp and and ID

What I need is the grid attribute table showing how many unique GPS ID's (A) there were with 30 seconds of an event (B) that was in the same grid

There might be several events in each grid so I would need the total number of unique GPS ID's that were around with in 30 seconds of each event for that grid.  Can someone please help point in the right direction.  I have only basic Python and SQL experience.

Comment: Any progress or attempted? If you show any progress would be easier to support you.

Comment: I have created a new table spatially joining all the GPS and events data to the grid ID number, so now there is a many to many relationship between ID number and grid ID.  I'm thinking I need to start with the groupby python function.  I basically want to ask:  "For each grid, find unique ID where TIME is <30 seconds> of Event = 1"